# Pausing a jquery function to wait for ajax content to load before continuing

Tags: jquery

I've got a script which loads some html into a div bases on a link the user clicks. I'm trying to create a crossfade type animation for this event. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
var loadInit = $('.thumbs a:first').attr("href");        
$('#loadTarget').load(loadInit);

$('.thumbs a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#loadTarget').hide('slow',loadContent);

    function loadContent() {
        $('#loadTarget').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#loadTarget').show('slow');
    }
    return false;
});
```

What I want to do is pause the script until the loadContent function has completely loaded the html and images associated with it. I'm getting this annoying flash as the first content is hidden and the new content loaded. Any ideas??

Comment: If you found my answer below to be the answer to your question, please vote it up and mark it as the answer so that other users can find it and solve their similar issues!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery load has a callback function that's called when load is complete:

```
$('#loadTarget').load(loadInit, function(response) {
    alert('complete!  Returned: ' + response);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

**ADDITION:**

```
function loadContent() {
$('#loadTarget').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()) //Wrong.
}
```

When you call `showNewContent()`, that executes immediately.  What you instead want to do is pass a pointer to the function by excluding the `()`.

```
function loadContent() {
$('#loadTarget').load(toLoad, showNewContent) //Right :)
}
```

This is what's causing your flicker as you're calling `showNewContent` immediately.

Comment: The second part is the answer.  The first bit doesn't really apply as the problem occurs on click not on first load (presumably).

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  But he had notes about chaining off of load and his syntax was a bit off so I thought I'd include the details of it.